# EE1 -> EE2 Upgrade; Updated Wygwam settings page error

Tags: wygwam

As stated in the title, I'm in the process of upgrading a site from EE1 to EE2, and I'm encountering errors on Wygwam's settings page. This is almost identical to [the issue Lisa raised](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/upgrade_wygwam_from_ee1_to_ee2), with the exception of the line number in error #3 being different.

Errors 1-3 are all above the CP menubar:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Filename: wygwam/helper.php
Line Number: 40

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
Filename: wygwam/helper.php
Line Number: 42

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
Filename: wygwam/mcp.wygwam.php
Line Number: 302
```

Errors 4-6 are immediately below the "Wygwam" heading (the one with the pencil graphic on the right-hand side), above the Preferences table:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: base
Filename: views/index.php
Line Number: 3

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: license_key
Filename: views/index.php
Line Number: 11

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: file_browser
Filename: views/index.php
Line Number: 28
```

The EE 1.7.1 site had Wygwam 2.6.3. The upgraded EE 2.5.5 site has Wygwam 2.7.

Comment: Sandwich, is this a site that I might be able to login to to troubleshoot? If so, can you send super admin and FTP details via support@pixelandtonic.com - and include a reference to this thread.  Thank you!

Comment: I'd probably look to uninstall and re-install first if it was an upgrade from EE1 to EE2. It seems like the correct changes to the database haven't been made. Running the install again should hopefully correct that.

Comment: Lisa: Email sent, thanks. :)
Ian: Seeing as it's a upgrade of an established EE1 site, I can't really afford to lose the Wygwam toolbar configurations at this stage in the game. Thanks though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by enabling the Wygwam fieldtype under Add-Ons->Fieldtypes.

Comment: Indeed. Apparently the EE1 -> EE2 upgrade process didn't activate the Wygwam fieldtype (although it did activate the Wygwam module). Vewey odd...